# Slack-Api: Sharing a message from one open channel in another

Tags: slack-api

is it possible to share a message from one open channel in another by slack's api (like you can do in the app)?

I understand how I can post a new message, but not how to share a message with its threads.

Comment: I do not think that is possible, but maybe someone else found a way.

Comment: I'm also interested in this. In the Slack desktop app, it's possible to do such sharing through the "Right Arrow" option when hovering over a message. I want to achieve the same using a bot.